# Getting maximum and minimum values in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I have dataframe which has two column in which I wanted get minimum and maximum values of the data frame I am new to pandas dataframe anyone suggest me how can I do it

df=

```
  data1 data2   name
   100   200    cand1
   300   400    cand1
   400   100    cand1
```

from the example above my output should look like as below

```
  data1  data2   name
   400    100    cand1
```

I have tried indivisual column like

`df[data1].max()`
`df[data2].min()` but this I want in a dataframe suggest me

Comment: First, I don't think ``df[data1].max()`` will actually work, you are missing apostrophe ``'...'``. second, what output are you actually expecting? what is the problem with the output that you posted in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost managed to do it correctly, so only a little bit of help is needed to make it work as you want it to work. No groupby or anything more complicated is needed.

First we make similar dataframe that you have.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'data1': [100, 200, 400], 'data2': [200, 400, 100], 'name': ['cand1', 'cand1', 'cand1']})
```

Then we take the max and min values of columns 'data1' and 'data2' respectively.

```
df['data1'] = df.data1.max()    
df['data2'] = df.data2.min()
```

Finally we drop all rows except the first one.

```
df = df.iloc[0:1,:]
```

And now we have the df as you need it to be.

```
data1  data2   name
400    100     cand1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby_agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
>>> df.groupby('name', as_index=False).agg({'data1': max, 'data2': min})
    name  data1  data2
0  cand1    400    100
```

Comment: @ShrilaxmiMS. You choose an answer with 3 operations rather than one. If you have a new name (cand2) in your dataframe, the chosen solution will not work.